# return doc firestore from service

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

How can I return the value of a Firestore document in real time from a service?

According to the Firebase documentation this is the way: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen?hl=es#web-modular-api

If I do it directly from the component it works fine (I get the data from the document), but how do I do it from a service?

I am using Angular 17 and Angularfire 17

I have tried the following:

service.ts

```
import { Firestore, doc, onSnapshot } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

private firestore = inject(Firestore);

async getUserMy(uid: string) {

    const docRef = doc(this.firestore, 'users', uid);
    const userMy = onSnapshot(docRef, async (doc) => {
      const user = doc.data() as UserMy;
      return user;
    }); 
    return userMy;

}
```

components.ts

```
private fs = inject(FirebaseService);

ngOnInit() {

 this.fs.getUserMy('xxxxxxxxx').then( (result) => {
   console.log(result);
 });

}
```

What I get in the console is this:

```
ƒ () {
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (macrotask && macrotask.state === "scheduled") {
            macrotask.invoke();
          }
        }, 10);
        return ret.apply(this, arguments);
  …
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a value, you can only do that once, so you should use a [one-time read](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) rather than a realtime listener that listens for updates.

With that change, your code would look like this:

```
async getUserMy(uid: string) {
    const docRef = doc(this.firestore, 'users', uid);
    const doc = await getDoc(docRef);
    const user = doc.data() as UserMy;
    return user;
}
```

---

If you want a [realtime listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen), you can't **return** a value - as a `return` statement only executes once. To report a stream of values back to the caller, you'll need to do something similar to the callback that you pass in to `onSnapshot` that you can then call multiple times, or an [Observable](https://angular.io/guide/observables).

---

You may also want to consider using [AngularFire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire), which wraps the Firestore API in such Angular primitives for you.

Comment: What I want is to use a real-time listener `onSnapchot`

Comment: If you want a realtime listener, you can't return a value - as a `return` statement only executes once. You'll need to do something similar to the callback that you pass in to `onSnapshot` that you can then call multiple times, or an [Observable](https://angular.io/guide/observables).